# Repeat a code in php for n times

Tags: php, loops

I have some code in php that do something. But I want some code that Repeat that code for example 10 or 20 times.

How can I do this?

For example this is my code:

```
<?php
  mysqli_query($con,
      "INSERT INTO x (x, y, z) VALUES ('a', 'b',c)");
  mail("a@v.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
  mysqli_query($con,
      "UPDATE x SET c=d WHERE x='a' AND y='b'");
?>
```

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called "looping" and there are a few ways to do it: `for`, `while`, `foreach` to name the most common.

Comment: use a loop ,,for($i=1;$i<=numberoftime;$i++){YOUR CODE HERE}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic programming concepts described in widely available official manuals and tutorials.

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: notice that your ``c`` value in your first mysql query is not encapsulate by ``'``

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `loop`, specifically, a `for` loop.

Here's how it looks:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    // code to repeat here
}
```

You can replace the 5 with the number of times you want to execute the code.

Here's [W3's page on PHP for loops](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

This is basic programming logic.  If you're interested in things like this, you should look into some online classes.

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools' PHP pages, they are horrible and filled with out of date incorrectness.  Please instead just link directly to the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Use while loop:

```
$x=1; 

while($x<=10) {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO x (x, y, z) VALUES ('a','b','c')");
    mail("a@v.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE x SET c=d WHERE x='a' AND y='b'");
    $x++; 
}
```

Comment: downvoted solely because although this works, a for loop is the better and simpler answer in this case.

Comment: @skrilled That isn't really a good reason for downvoting. This is technically accurate, though the question itself is a real stinker, and it can be argued that bottom-feeding off basic questions like this isn't very helpful.

Comment: Well I'll remove my downvote, I just don't want people assuming this is the best solution by any means.

Comment: @skrilled What makes the `for` better than the `while`? They are both equal in performance. The complexity difference between the two is subjective..

Comment: It's not that for is better than while in all cases or visa versa, it's that you are doing something very specifically that for was built to do. It's much easier to read in production code when someone uses loops with the forethought of why they are using the loop. Setting a counter and incrementing it manually and etc is simply recreating a wheel, and that's unnecessary.

Comment: i need to say that a ``while`` loop is faster in this case then a ``for`` loop. the real problem i see in this answer is the formatting. upvote

Comment: Incorrect - Test vs Avg Execution Time in a case like this: for loop        23.44 ms, while loop      24.65 ms, do while loop   22.96 ms

Comment: So not only does it benchmark worse, it is simply a means of avoiding something prebuilt that does it for you in the spirit of doing it yourself and even slower. Don't claim something is faster when you don't have proof that it is, and every benchmark site on earth says you are wrong. Downvoted to negate his upvote, as this is not the  best answer on this page and does not deserve a place above it.

Comment: incorrect - http://codepad.org/RM8sKG7j notice that i added ``preincrement`` to make it more faster

Comment: @skrilled I think you meant 23.44 microseconds vs 24.65 microseconds, not milliseconds. The performance difference between the two is irrelevant in almost any real-world use case scenario.

Comment: Sory I have another question.<br> Is it possible to use function to use loop? for example I have test() function. And I want to repeat it for 10 times. Can you enplane it with php code?

Comment: yes ssergei, you're right it's generally irrelevant - he claimed it was faster when the results are mixed at best. apparently codepad gets a different benchmark than a vast chunk of the results i've found on google. http://www.svachon.com/blog/benchmark-php-reverse-array-while-vs-for-vs-foreach/

Comment: for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) test();

Comment: dnt trust benchmarks from over 2 years ;)

Comment: Then I'll trust my own benchmark on php 5.5.8 (your codepad script) - time while: 0.45764493942261 | time for: 0.42423701286316

Comment: The vast majority of benchmarks show the for loop as being faster, you must be looking at a very specific version or something. either way, it's such an insignificant difference that my for loop ran faster, that I'll simply end with this: the for loop looks better and is easier to read and makes more sense than manually recreating a wheel.

Comment: i admit it, performance change from version to version and from system to system

Comment: @skrilled Benchmarks are of limited value because they seldom reflect real-world usage. Knowing that, a difference of 0.03 seconds is known as "trivial" or within the margin of error. Micro-optimization is not a good data point to use when deciding what control structures one uses. I am with you that `for` is more straightforward, there is no real argument against using `while`, just as there is no real argument against using C-style braces. It is, in practical terms, 100% preference.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would use a for loop for this.  Assuming you are using PHP5:

```
for (init counter; test counter; increment counter) {
code to be executed;
}
```

For example:

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
}
?>
```

More info can be found [here](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: Some people are more hard-line about it than others, Brett, but the short answer is: it isn't the official documentation. No third-party site, no matter how well-maintained, is going to be a better authority than the free and public native documentation. In the case of W3Schools, there is a history of the site NOT being well-maintained, and something of an active campaign against the site has become a part of programming pop culture. http://www.w3fools.com/ is the home of the organized criticism, though I would also point out that the criticism site is too out of date.

Comment: @Chris I changed the link to the PHP manual site when I saw the comment on another answer.  But thank you for letting me know, I was curious as to why there was so much hate toward that site.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this guys answer should fix that now.